# How to get cv::calcOpticalFlowSF to work?

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I am useing the 2.4.4 version of OpenCV. - i know its a beta 
but there is an example about [`cv::calcOpticalFlowSF`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=calcopticalflowsf#void%20calcOpticalFlowSF%28Mat&%20from,%20Mat&%20to,%20Mat&%20flow,%20int%20layers,%20int%20averaging_block_size,%20int%20max_flow%29) the method in the example folder called: `simpleflow_demo.cpp`. But when i copy this demo and use it  with my input images, it starts processing and after some seconds it came back a crash report. 
The documentation about the method is a little bit strange, saying the output files are a x- and yflow instead of the `cv::Mat& flow` which the method actually wants. 
Any ideas how to fix the problem to get the function working?

Comment: You need to post the actual details of the crash report. The bit about the X and Y flow being separate are for the C API, not the C++ API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple demo that worked for me, then modify for your needs (display help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693561/opencv-displaying-a-2-channel-image-optical-flow)):

```
Mat frame1 = imread("/home/radford/Desktop/1.png");
Mat frame2 = imread("/home/radford/Desktop/2.png");

namedWindow("flow");
Mat flow;

calcOpticalFlowSF(frame1, frame2, flow, 3, 2, 4);

Mat xy[2];
split(flow, xy);

//calculate angle and magnitude
Mat magnitude, angle;
cartToPolar(xy[0], xy[1], magnitude, angle, true);

//translate magnitude to range [0;1]
double mag_max;
minMaxLoc(magnitude, 0, &mag_max);
magnitude.convertTo(magnitude, -1, 1.0/mag_max);

//build hsv image
Mat _hsv[3], hsv;
_hsv[0] = angle;
_hsv[1] = Mat::ones(angle.size(), CV_32F);
_hsv[2] = magnitude;
merge(_hsv, 3, hsv);

//convert to BGR and show
Mat bgr;//CV_32FC3 matrix
cvtColor(hsv, bgr, COLOR_HSV2BGR);
imshow("flow", bgr);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thank you now i got opticalFlow DualTVL1 working with this too.

Comment: Thank you, your code helped a lot! But I stil have problems with gray images: `cv::cvtColor(image1Re, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); cv::cvtColor(image2Re, prevgray, CV_BGR2GRAY);` Using: gray and prevgray as input intead of your frame1 and frame2. Do you know whats going wrong in this case?

Comment: Just from looking at the variable names in the calcOpticalFlowSF doc, it seems like color is utilized in the algorithm and must be necessary as an input.

Answer (score 0):

In the example opencv/samples/cpp/simpleflow_demo.cpp there is a code block

```
if (frame1.type() != 16 || frame2.type() != 16) {
    printf(APP_NAME "Images should be of equal type CV_8UC3\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

So, grey images should be converted to CV_8UC3. For example using cvtColor(grey, grey3, CV_GRAY2RGB);