# What does the output array contain in calcOpticalFlowSF

Tags: opencv

I need to read the displacement of each pixel in each stage using the Optical flow - **Simple Flow** tracking algorithm.
I tried the code mentioned here:
[How to make Simpleflow work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974453/how-to-get-cvcalcopticalflowsf-to-work/14986328#14986328)

The code works fine. However, I don't know what does the flow array contain because its values have a strange format, does it contain the **displacement** or the **new position** of the pixel or non of them? And is there any way to read these values in order to track the pixel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After readin their paper [SimpleFlow: A Non-iterative, Sublinear Optical Flow Algorithm](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs252-S11/projects/reports/project1_report.pdf), authors clearly state that the resulting flow matrice contains the displacement of the pixel, i.e. the pixel p1 in the Ft image is at the position (x,y), and the position of p1 in the Ft+i is (x+u, y+v), (u,v) are the values saved in the resulting flow matrice for each pixel from Ft.