# How to display 2 channels image with cv::imshow?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to convert RGB to Lab and then combine a and b channels into one. The conversion and splitting into channels works fine. But when I try to merge a and b channels it breaks at imshow.

```
Mat src;
Mat lab;
Mat dstL, dsta, dstb;
Mat dstab;
char fname[MAX_PATH];

while (openFileDlg(fname))
{

    src = imread(fname);

    GaussianBlur(src, src, Size(5, 5), 0, 0);
    cvtColor(src, lab, CV_BGR2Lab);
    //dstab = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_16SC2);

    Mat channel[3];
    vector<Mat> ab;

    split(lab, channel);

    Mat dstL = channel[0];
    Mat dsta = channel[1];
    Mat dstb = channel[2];

    ab.push_back(dsta);
    ab.push_back(dstb);

    merge(ab, dstab);
    imshow("ab component", dstab);

    imshow("Lab", lab);
    imshow("L component", dstL);
    imshow("a component", dsta);
    imshow("b component", dstb);
}
```

Comment: imshow probably doesn't know how to visualize the 2 channel image. Try adding a third channel with all 0s or other value that lets you see the result clearly

Comment: You can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693561/opencv-displaying-a-2-channel-image-optical-flow

Comment: i added a third channel with 0s and it worked. Thank you

Comment: please post what you did as an answer and accept it so that it's useful for others in the future

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV displaying a 2-channel image (optical flow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693561/opencv-displaying-a-2-channel-image-optical-flow)